# Is there an equivalent of Python's __rmul__ in C++?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, overloading

Python 3 allows overloading of `*`.

For example,

`a*b`

Allows `a` to define the result by providing  a `__mul__` method.

If however that method returns `NotImplemented,` the `__rmul__` method on `b` is called (if it exists) to give the result. This is documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types).

One advantage of this is that I can make on object `b` that operates on `a` without knowing the class of `a`.

Is there an equivalent to `__rmul__` in C++, or a way of achieving the same or a similar thing?

Comment: *If however that method returns NotImplemented* --  I guess this is Python's roundabout way of doing [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae).

Answer (score 5):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but according to my understanding, you need to overload an operator for 2 different classes.

You can do something like this as under:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    int integer;
};

class B
{
public:
    double decimal;
};

//A * B
double operator*(A a, B b)
{
    return a.integer * b.decimal;
}

int main() 
{
    A a{12}; B b{2};
    double c = a * b;

    std::cout << c;
}
```

In the above example, I've overloaded operator* to multiply 2 objects of type A and B. But it only works for a * b, not b * a. So you can do something like this:

```
//B * A
double operator*(B b, A a)
{
    return a.integer * b.decimal;
}
```